# ShearingTransform and Dynamic

Tags: graphics, programming, dynamic

Background: I have a geometric transformation composed of a `RotationTransform`, `ScalingTransform` and `ShearingTransform`, I can use dynamic constructs with rotations and scalings but this does not (seem to) work with the `ShearingTransform`.

Consider the following snippet:

```
  DynamicModule[{shr, deg = 30},
   shr0 = ShearingTransform[deg Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}];
   shr1 = Dynamic[ShearingTransform[deg Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]];
   shr2 = ShearingTransform[Dynamic[deg Degree], {1, 0}, {0, 1}];
  Column[{
     Slider[Dynamic[deg], {0, 90, 1}],
     GeometricTransformation[{Blue,
       Rectangle[{0, 0}, {3, 1}]},
      shr0] // Graphics}
   ]]
```

Note that the snippet does not work (as expected) : moving the slider does not change the angle of the shear. See `shr1` and `shr2` for alternatives I have already tried.

**Question: How can I make the angle in a `ShearingTransform` dynamic, such that it works in the context of the snippet above?**

Comment: Fixing it is one thing, but understanding why exactly it doesn't work is more interesting.  Here's another example which I don't understand completely right now: `DynamicModule[{a, b},
 b := f[a];
 {Slider[Dynamic[a], {0, 1}], Dynamic[a], 
  Dynamic[b, TrackedSymbols -> {a}]}
 ]`  (`f` is an inert head here)

Comment: And here's another one, analogous to Leonid's example, which does appear to work at first: `DynamicModule[{a, b},
 b := f[a];
 {Slider[Dynamic[a], {0, 1}], Dynamic[a], 
  Dynamic[b, TrackedSymbols -> {a}]},
 Initialization :> (a = 0.4444)
 ]`.  But now try this for both versions: select the output and press Ctrl-Shift-I to convert to InputForm and see what's in the `DynamicModule`.  Now convert back to StandardForm (Ctrl-Shift-N), and see again what happens.  Leonid's version got "broken" while the first version picked up `a` value for `b` but `b` still won't update.

Comment: It probably has to do something with how `DynamicModule` variables are owned by the Front End and not the kernel.  Also note that when using `Module` (making the variables be owned by the kernel), the example seems to work.

Comment: @Szabolcs The effects you describe are likely due to caching. Try this, for instance: `DynamicModule[{a, b}, 
 b := f[a]; {Slider[Dynamic[a, (a = #; Update[Unevaluated[b]]) &], {0, 1}],  Dynamic[a],  Dynamic[b]}]`

Comment: @Leonid It seems just *mentioning* `b` changes the behaviour:  you could use `(a = #; b) &` as the second arg in `Dynamic`---it's enough to "fix" it.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think I have already run into this issue a couple of times before, and also recall that there were some related discussions on Mathgroup.

Comment: @Leonid If you find them, do post a link please.

Comment: @Szabolcs [Here is one](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/d05b49e79435e6c5). There was a larger one, but it disappeared from the web somehow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several things to understand here, but all of them center around a common theme.  Exactly *what* is evaluating, and exactly *when*?  It looks like you're just trying to guess what's going on, but guessing is bad... you really should understand the evaluation model.

#### A: Problems with the code in the question

1. The method in the question would not have worked under normal evaluation without `Dynamic` or `DynamicModule` because it used `Set` (`=`) rather than `SetDelayed` (`:=`).  i.e.,

   ```
   a=1;
   b=f[a];
   a=2;
   b

   (* f[1] *)
   ```

   So, your example fails immediately because what it assigned to `shr0` was not `ShearingTransform[deg Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]`, but `ShearingTransform[30 Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]`.  Changing `deg` will never again help you.
2. You can't just put `Dynamic` anywhere and expect it to delay evaluation.  For example, the following:

   ```
   a=2; 2 + Dynamic[a]
   ```

   will not give you four, and putting a `Slider` on the value of `a` would not allow you to see the result of `2+a`.  I've written on this subject ad nauseum before...a bit in this forum and to a much greater extent [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Feb/msg00424.html).

   `Dynamic` works in exactly two places... where it directly translates into output you wish to see visibly, or where it is the value of a control.  Every time you use `Dynamic`, you need to think about that... am I seeing the result?  Am I setting the value from a control?  If not, you are misusing `Dynamic` and will probably not get the effect you intended.

#### B: Misconceptions in the comments and other answers

1. An issue which is causing confusion among the commenters is that `DynamicModule`, sadly, does not support `SetDelayed` on its member variables.  `SetDelayed` is silently translated to `Set`.

   ```
   ToBoxes[DynamicModule[{a = 5, b}, b := a; Dynamic[b]], StandardForm]

   (* DynamicModuleBox[{a$$ = 5, b$$ = 5}, 
     DynamicBox[ToBoxes[b$$, StandardForm]], DynamicModuleValues :> {}] *)
   ```

   Note the output shows that what was assigned to `b` was `5`, not `a`.  And the assignment is immediate, not delayed.
2. [Leonid's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6286/5) very subtly "works around" the issue by flipping evaluation orders around, but ultimately fails because it can't keep the evaluation order flipped forever.  To boil down the essential point of Leonid's example, we have:

   ```
   DynamicModule[{a, b}, b := f[a]; {Slider[Dynamic[a]], Dynamic[b]},
       Initialization :> (a = 0)]
   ```

   As long as `Dynamic[b]` always sends `f[a]` to the kernel, things will work.  But if, at any point, the `Dynamic` instead sends `f[0]` (or any other value of `a`), the jig is up, and `Dynamic[b]` will stay frozen forever.  Both the kernel and the FE have copies of `a` and `b` lying around, and for reasons which are outside of the scope of this question, this happens to cause the FE to think `b=f[a]` while the kernel thinks `b=f[0]`.  But if they ever have to sync up values, the jig is definitely up.  And the FE always syncs up values when determining what to save to disk or when making a clipboard copy of a `DynamicModule`.  So closing/reopening the file or pasting a copy of the resulting cell will show that the association is broken in both my toy example and Leonid's full example.

#### C: The right approach

So what would I suggest?  First, you have to expand the scope of the `Dynamic` to fully cover the output.  Leonid's example does that correctly, as will mine.  And Leonid's example would work perfectly if you simply removed `shr0` and just used the full rhs value directly in the `Dynamic`, but I'll assume that you have good reason to want to modularize this.  The trick, then, is to use `DynamicWrapper` to do the updating we might have preferred to do via `SetDelayed`.  First, let's see how this would apply to the simple example above:

```
DynamicModule[{a, b}, {Slider[Dynamic[a]], DynamicWrapper[Dynamic[b], b = f[a]]}]
```

`DynamicWrapper`, like `Dynamic`, evaluates its contents when they appear onscreen.  By wrapping `Dynamic[b]` with `DynamicWrapper`, I guarantee that the evaluation `b=f[a]` will always happen at the right time for `Dynamic[b]` to display the proper result.

So, let's see the final result in action:

```
DynamicModule[{shr, deg = 30},
 Column[{Slider[Dynamic[deg], {0, 90, 1}], 
   DynamicWrapper[
    Dynamic[GeometricTransformation[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {3, 1}]},
        shr] // Graphics], 
    shr = ShearingTransform[deg Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]]}]]
```

This code, as all good `DynamicModule` code should, will survive restarts of the kernel and the FE, copy/paste, and closing/reopening of the file.

Comment: +1 For the advice where dynamic works. Learned that from the tutorials, but it took me much longer.

Comment: I should point out one thing that's outdated in my linked content...when I wrote that, the "invisible Dynamic" trick was the only option for getting things to evaluate you didn't want to see.  Now `DynamicWrapper` is really the preferred way, as I outlined in this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this clears things up.

Comment: @JohnFultz I was just about to ask a 'related question' because I have the same problems again. As you wrote in your answer this was more or less to be expected.  I hope I can fix the issue with the help of the clarification in this answer.

Comment: And I did! I feel so much more confident with Dynamic now. ( This is such a unique place in the Mma universe. )

Comment: Welcome back! Glad you got the time to get us to stop guessing

Comment: Naive `InheritScope->True` doesn't seem to survive the full synch. How would you deal with that? `DynamicModule[{x}, {Slider@Dynamic@x, 
  Button["h", 
   CreateDialog@DynamicModule[{}, Dynamic[x], InheritScope -> True]]}]`

Answer (score 5):

> **NOTE:** This answer fails subtly when closing and reopening the notebook. Please see Section B.2 in [John Fultz's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6301/5) for an explanation of why it fails and Section C in his answer for the correct approach.
>
> I've retained my original answer below to aid the discussion in John's answer and for people to learn from mistakes arising from what appears to be correct code at first glance, but with subtle points of failure.

---

This is what you need:

```
DynamicModule[{deg, shr0},
   shr0 = ShearingTransform[deg Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}];
   Column[{
     Slider[Dynamic[deg], {0, 90, 1}],
     Dynamic[
       Graphics[
         GeometricTransformation[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {3, 1}]}, shr0]
       ], 
       Initialization :> (deg = 30)]
    }]]
```

Comment: Could you take a look at my comments on the main post, and the two code snippets?  I don't really understand what is happening here, why your version seems to work at first while removing the Initialization seems to break it.  I'm going to look at the cell expressions now instead of converting to InputForm.

Comment: Just copying the cell expression to a new cell (and breaking the "hidden" front end variables) has the same effect on the two version as converting to InputForm and back.  The fact that these variables are owned by the front end are key to understanding what is happening, but right now it just became even more mysterious to me.  I really wonder if your solution is robust enough to survive closing and re-opening the notebook (or being put in a CDF, which is the same).

Comment: If that does it, then I have been making life too difficult for myself. Will try now.

Comment: @ndroock1 If you're going to put this in a CDF, do try to save and reopen the notebook and see if the slider still works or not.  **Edit:** I just tried, and as I suspected, a save/reload breaks it.

Comment: Very helpful answer for me. I have overlooked Initialization entirely.

Comment: @Szabolcs Not using CDFs but I must remember this. Do you see alternative solutions, more stable ?

Comment: @ndroock1 My main concern now is that my assumptions have been violated, my world is broken now, and I can't move on until I understand what's going on here.  This version seems to work superficially, but not after closing/reopening the notebook, even though it should.

Comment: @Szabolcs I can't offer any explanation. This behavior seems to violate the documentation for `DynamicModule`. But, you know what, I always use kernel vars in my UI-s, and I don't care if that is or is not "politically correct". If I can't make it work with the kernels vars, I try to find a way which would. I already said many times that I much prefer the open DOM models for UI programming, such as Java Swing or Javascript DOM. My personal experience is that the pain/gain ratio for "proper" UI coding in M is just too high for me. Perhaps it's just me, and I don't encourage this viewpoint.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin - I agree ( in sofar ) that I think that there is a tipping point after which Mma becomes too tiresome for developing GUIs. I suppose that point differs for all of us.

Comment: @ndroock1 I have developed quite complex UI-s in Mathematica - my point is that so far I had no problems doing that and practically avoiding `DynamicModule` in favor of `Module`. I prefer my variables to live in the kernel, and don't mind re-creating the state. I know that in principle, there can be inconsistencies from that, but in practice, I was always able to find workarounds. But, again, I don't suggest to others to have the same attitude.

Comment: @ndroock1 Thanks for the accept. If you localize the variables by `Module` rather than `DynamicModule`, then the result will survive the reloading.

Comment: This does not appear to work on version 7. :-/

Comment: **To the downvoter**: I only keep this answer because it is referenced by the better one by John Fultz, and was an integral part of the discussion. One more downvote, and I am deleting it (which will make the discussion less complete for lower-rep users).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, I debated whether to reference your answer in my own, and I hope that I didn't cause you any consternation in doing so (but deeply apologize if I did).  I think it's enlightening to explore why your answer appears to work at first, and why it fails later.  I immediately expected the latter, but had to ponder a bit before I could fully answer the former.  I have occasionally wished that the StackExchange format didn't penalize answers which are educational even when they're not entirely complete or correct in some way.

Comment: @JohnFultz I actually think that it was a very good idea to reference it and explain why it was wrong, and things became more clear this way. Normally I delete my sub-optimal answers, and particularly here I was somewhat outside of the part of Mathematica where I am confident. In this particular case, I decided to leave the answer as an integral part of the discussion, but was upset that people don't understand it and downvote. Actually, I am probably not going to delete the answer anyway - there are always folks who misinterpret things, but more will benefit from seeing this failed code too.

Comment: @JohnFultz Actually, upon some reflection, I think there was some truth with the downvoter. Since I only keep the answer to supplement the discussion in yours and keep it complete, I should have edited it and clearly say so at the start of my answer. Will do that now.

Comment: Wow, this must be the first time I've ever seen Leonid downvoted! @JohnFultz I've reorganized your answer into sections to aid the flow of reading. Leonid, I've added a bit more explanatory and non-glaring note in your answer (and referenced the appropriate parts in John's answer). To both: feel free to edit further or rollback parts of my edits if you don't like it.

Comment: @R.M. Thanks for a nice and expanded reformulation of my note. I should have done that myself but didn't feel like doing this at this time.

Comment: @R.M. Looks good.  Thanks.