# Working with DynamicModule: SetDelayed + OwnValues

Tags: scoping, variable-definitions, gui-construction, guidelines

Shortly, definitions in form of e.g. `x:= RandomReal[]` have to be avoided inside `DynamicModule[{x}, ...]`. Why?, this `Prints` immediately:

```
DynamicModule[{x}, x := Print[1]; {}]
```

It hit us hard in the past, e.g.:

- [Button evaluation inside DynamicModule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29129/5478)
- comments under [ShearingTransform and Dynamic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/shearingtransform-and-dynamic/6301#comment17796_6284)
- comments under [How to combine manipulate and eventhandler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66696/how-to-combine-manipulate-and-eventhandler#comment186815_66767)

So what is the official rule here?

> ref / DynamicModule / Details and Options / (-4)th bullet point
>
> Ordinary values of symbols are saved in the first argument of the `DynamicModule`; other values are saved in the setting for the `DynamicModuleValues` option.

This is almost useless since "Ordinary values of symbols" and "other values" have no real meaning in *Mathematica*.

> J. Fultz in [ShearingTransform and Dynamic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6301/5478):
>
> An issue which is causing confusion among the commenters is that `DynamicModule`, sadly, does not support `SetDelayed` on its member variables.  `SetDelayed` is silently translated to `Set`.

Closer but not quite there yet, `x[]:=RandomReal[]` will work well.

---

Comment: really intriguing and helpful!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

J. Fultz' answer indicates that it is not a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) but a [feature](/questions/tagged/feature) which needs better documentation.

Get a habit of defining your procedures with `[]`, e.g. `f[]:=Print[1]`. (Which creates `DownValues` instead of `OwnValues`).

`DynamicModule` saves its variables' `OwnValues` in the first argument of that `DynamicModule`. Which does not support `SetDelayed` and is sliently translated to `Set`. (e.g. `DynamicModule[{x := RandomReal[]}, {}]` is left unevaluated)

Values other than `OwnValues` will be saved in `DynamicModuleValues` option and work as expected.

#### "Proof"

```
InputForm @ DynamicModule[{x}, x[] := RandomReal[]; {}]
```

> ```
> DynamicModule[{x}, 
>     {}, 
>     DynamicModuleValues :> {{DownValues[x] = {HoldPattern[x[]] :> RandomReal[]}}}
> ]
> ```

```
 InputForm @ DynamicModule[{x}, x := RandomReal[]; {}]
```

> ```
> DynamicModule[{x = 0.20406205529616095}, 
>     {}, 
>     DynamicModuleValues :> {}
> ]
> ```

---

I've already sent a report with a request to improve `DynamicModule's` documentation:

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3676288] was created.
>
> [...] I have filed a suggestion with the appropriate development team requesting that we better document how `DynamicModule` handles `SetDelayed` `OwnValues`. [...]

Comment: As I was reading the question I wondered why I had not personally been bitten by this that I could recall, but seeing this answer I realize that I already use the form `f[]` the vast majority of the time, inside or outside of `DynamicModule`.  I have for years felt that this is superior in general as it allows passing Symbol names without unexpected evaluation, and because to me it better follows the apparent paradigm of the language.  I personally quite *dislike* the exceptions such as `Quit` that have action as bare Symbols.  IMHO `f[]` should be the guideline everywhere.

Comment: A post related to my thoughts above: [(32202)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32202/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yep, this also helps with accidental reloading  (`Get`) of packages. Where otherwise delayed `OwnValues` could destructively interfere.