# How to properly initialize a list variable that is dynamically updated?

Tags: dynamic

The below example works to initialize the Gauge, but it does not initialize `sf` until we interact with the gauge.

```
DynamicModule[{xa, x0 = 1, dx = 1, xb, xbScaled, fa, fb, fbScaled, 
  points, sf, sf2, scaledPoints, somePolys},
 somePolys = {1 + x, 0.5 - 0.1*x, 1 - 0.1*x^2, 
   1 - x - 0.2*x^2 + 0.05*x^3};
 xa = x0;
 xb = x0 + dx;
 xbScaled := x0 + dx*sf;
 fa = somePolys /. x -> xa;
 fb = somePolys /. x -> xb;
 fbScaled := fa + (fb - fa)/(xb - xa)*(sf - 1)*dx;
 points = MapThread[{{xa, #1}, {xb, #2}} &, {fa, fb}];
 scaledPoints := 
  MapThread[{{xa, #1}, {#3, #2}} &, {fa, fbScaled, xbScaled}];
 {
   sf2 = {0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7};
   HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[sf2, (sf2 = #; sf = sf2;) &], 
    GaugeStyle -> 97],
   Dynamic[xbScaled],
   Dynamic[scaledPoints],
   Dynamic[Definition[xbScaled]]
   } // Column
 ]
```

The initial output before interacting with the Gauge at all looks like this, because `sf` has not been initialized yet.

[image: Initial output before interaction with Gauge]

After interacting with the gauge, `sf` is given a useable definition and `xbScaled` and `fbScaled` can be computed properly via their definitions.

[image: Output after gauge interaction]

The definition of the `Gauge` above is a workaround. I would really like to initialize `sf` and have the `Gauge` be defined like this:

`HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[sf], GaugeStyle -> 97]`

And then replace all instances of `sf2` with `sf`. I would have expected this to work because the definition of `xbScaled` is `SetDelayed`, but when I do that, it seems like that definition is not created *before* `sf` is initialized:

```
(* I would expect this to always have sf in the definition since it is SetDelayed*)
xbScaled:=x0+dx*sf;
sf={0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5};
(*definition of xbScaled appears to contain the initialized values of sf,
 and not the symbol sf itself. Thus, it is not updated.*)
Dynamic[xbScaled]
```

Even though `xbScaled` is set delayed, initializing `sf` (instead of `sf2` in the workaround) gives the definition of `xbScaled` with the initialized values of `sf`, rather than containing the `sf` symbol.

So I maybe the ultimate question boils down to this: how can I use SetDelayed symbols that are meant to be Dynamic inside of a DynamicModule and properly initialize the variables they depend on without clobbering the definition of the delayed variables?

(Please edit the post if you believe the ultimate question should be different)

Comment: I can't commit to answer your specific case but I guess knowing this will save your time and will help to solve this: [121585](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121585/5478)

Comment: `Simply replace `{sf2 {0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7};` by `{sf2 = sf = {0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7};`

Comment: @DanielHuber Your "simple" suggestion does not solve the problem at all. Making your suggested change causes `xbScaled` to no longer be connected to the Gauge (or `sf`). That was the whole premise of the question.

Comment: @Kuba it took me some experimentation, but the answer you linked helped me to make this example work as intended. Thank you! I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following post has some clues as
to why the SetDelayed does not work (essentially, DynamicModule does not support SetDelayed) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121585/5478.

The following code does what I intended, but it is not obvious why this is needed. It feels like a hack. One needs to use square brackets `[]` in all the variable names that depend on the initialized variables (in this case everything that depends on `sf`), both the definition and usage, in order to maintain the unevaluated form in the definition. This allows one to maintain dynamicity when the variable is updated (`sf` in this example).

```
DynamicModule[{xa, x0 = 1, dx = 1, xb, xbScaled, fa, fb, fbScaled, 
  points, sf, sf2, scaledPoints, somePolys},
 somePolys = {1 + x, 0.5 - 0.1*x, 1 - 0.1*x^2, 
   1 - x - 0.2*x^2 + 0.05*x^3};
 xa = x0;
 xb = x0 + dx;
 xbScaled[] := x0 + dx*sf;
 fa = somePolys /. x -> xa;
 fb = somePolys /. x -> xb;
 fbScaled[] := fa + (fb - fa)/(xb - xa)*(sf - 1)*dx;
 points = MapThread[{{xa, #1}, {xb, #2}} &, {fa, fb}];
 scaledPoints[] := 
  MapThread[{{xa, #1}, {#3, #2}} &, {fa, fbScaled[], xbScaled[]}];
 {
   sf = {0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7};
   HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[sf], GaugeStyle -> 97],
   Dynamic[xbScaled[]],
   Dynamic[scaledPoints[]],
   Dynamic[fbScaled[]],
   Dynamic[Definition[xbScaled[]]]
   } // Column
 ]
```

The output upon first execution before interacting with  the `gauge`:
[image]

And adjusting the `Gauge` updates the various `Dynamic` outputs.