# Make `Manipulate` work despite `Clear["Global`*"]`

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

What is the correct way to stop all my `Manipulate` cells from breaking every time I issue `` ClearAll["Global`*"] `` command?

Here's an attempt below, it does not survive `` ClearAll["Global`*"] ``, as the definition of `clean` does not get saved.

```
x = Range[100];
clean[x_] := Module[{y = 5}, x*5];

With[{xLocal = x, cleanLocal = clean},
 Manipulate[
  ListPlot[cleanLocal[xLocal], PlotLabel -> k], {k, 1, 5, 1}, 
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
 ]
```

Here's an example of what I see (things break if `` ClearAll["Global`*"] `` is run in a different cell than `Manipulate`)

[image]

Comment: You could "localize" your definitions to the `With` or some other localizing construct. You could put your definitions into a context other than Global (although I suspect that's not really the kind of thing you were looking for).

Comment: What I mean by the "localizing" comment is to effectively inline things or make them anonymous: `With[{xLocal = Range[100], cleanLocal = Module[{y = 5}, #*5] &}, ... ]`

Comment: I used With to localize variables above, however that fails

Comment: You can localize the variables to the cell with `DynamicModule` via something like `DynamicModule[{x, clean}, x = Range[100]; clean[x_] := ...;
 Manipulate[...]]`

Comment: I guess we need to go deeper into what `With` actually does. `With` doesn't transfer the definition of `x` to `xLocal`. It replaces every instance of `xLocal` inside of the `With` with `x`. And, of course, it's the `x` that gets cleared, resulting in what you see. I put "localize" in quotes to emphasize that it was a special type of localizing. I don't see how you're going to get `With` to work the way you're trying. If you don't want to inline your definitions like I (and JasonB) suggested, then you need to find some other way to "hide" those definitions from the Global context.

Comment: Maybe I'll try to be even clearer... In the WolframLanguage, there are no truly local variables. Everything is global. That doesn't mean everything is in the Global context. I just mean that every symbol is accessible from anywhere--you just need to know its name (the full name including context path). The way some "localizing" constructs (like Module) work, is to just create special, difficult-to-accidentally-refer-to names.

Comment: Not to be too glib, but ```ClearAll["Global`*"]``` is a pretty blunt instrument. Perhaps use a more targeted clearing expression?

Comment: I don't think `SaveDefinitions` works the way you think it does. The saved definitions are executed when the `DynamicModule` is instantiated in the front end. If you change the defnition of `clean` while the `Manipulate` is running, `Maniupulate` will not re-execute the save definition. Since `clean` is global, its value is shared. Clear it, and it is undefined throughout the kernel. Copy a broken `Manipulate` output and paste it, and the saved definition will be executed again, restoring the original definition. Localize the symbol `clean` and its definition in `Manipulate` to protect it.

Comment: @Goofy Ohhh! Maybe the OP was thinking that `SaveDefinitions` was analogous to `Protect`/`Protected`! I was so confused. Yeah, saving a symbol's definition doesn't mean that you can't later clear it.

Comment: I guess I need something like "with"  that saves copy of the value to a local symbol. Ie a=b.clone() in Python

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Copying one symbol into another](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19903/5478) and store `ClearAll`-persistent values as DynamicModule variables.

```
copySymbol // Attributes = {HoldAll}
copySymbol[new_Symbol, old_Symbol] := Language`ExtendedDefinition[new] = 
  Language`ExtendedDefinition[old] /. HoldPattern[old] :> new
```

```
x = Range[100];
clean[x_] := Module[{y = 5}, x*5];


DynamicModule[{xLocal = x, cleanLocal}
, copySymbol[cleanLocal, clean]

; Manipulate[
    ListPlot[cleanLocal[xLocal], PlotLabel -> k]
  , {k, 1, 5, 1}
  ]
]
```

`SaveDefinitions` is not needed because it saves other than DM's variables and  loads them on initialization only. They are still `` Global` ``  so it will break.

For `DynamicModule` variables, their values are saved automatically ([watch out for SetDelayed OwnValues maybe](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121584/5478)) and shielded from `ClearAll` because they end up in `` FE` ``  context.

But maybe it is worth adjusting your workflow so that `` Clear["Global`*"] `` won't affect your Manipulates. A specific solution would require more insight into your work though.

Comment: Thanks.....is this method robust against restarting Mathematica? Ie, I want my demos to still work when I reopen the notebook? Or is the "copy all relevant code inside manipulate block" the only reasonable way?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov have you tried, I think it should work.

Comment: Yes it works for this example, thanks! BTW why is it that you need to call `copySymbol` for `clean` but not for `xLocal`, is it because of `DownValues` that don't get copied by `DynamicModule`?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov `x` evaluates to a range so the symbol reference is gone. `clean` does not evaluate to anything so cleanLocal still references that symbol which may be cleared.