# How to cache results of "Animate" in NotebookDirectory?

Tags: front-end, animation, wolfram-cloud

I have some `Animate` cells in my notebook using pattern `Animate[doplot[i],...]`. When I deploy the notebook on the Web, I want the Animations to display without needing to evaluate any cells, but now now it just prints `doplot[i]`.

What is the correct way to cache these animations?

I wrapped my Animate using `DynamicModule` and used `SaveDefinitions->True` option and it appears to [work](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/twitter-complex-animate.nb), but maybe an overkill, what' the correct way to do this?

(Got idea from Kuba's [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/293183/217) on saving things for Manipulate)

Comment: If you use`ListAnimate` and provide a set of frames the data will be baked in and everything will just work

Comment: @b3m2a1 I could do it, but don't really want to rewrite all my notebooks, which use Animate due to shorter syntax

Comment: Did you ensure that doplot[i] and  i are defined? A workaround would be to replace  doplot[i] and  i by explicit code.

Comment: @DanielHuber the issue is that definitions are not saved, you need to manually evaluate dependent cells for them to work, example [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-rotational-eval-angles.nb)